# Saving an object with foreign key does not return ID in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a cinema reservation system where user can add movies and then they can add date to each movie. It works fine, but when a user adds a date, there is no error, but it saves to the database with movie_id = null.

How can I solve it?

Movie.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;
 
    private String category;

    @Column( columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    private Integer lenght;

    private Integer minAge;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String imageUrl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Repertoire> repertoires;

    public Movie() {
   }
}
```

Repertoire.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Repertoire {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;
}
```

MovieController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieController {

    private MovieRepo movieRepo;
    private RepertoireRepo repertoireRepo;

    @Autowired
    public MovieController(MovieRepo movieRepo, RepertoireRepo repertoireRepo) {
        this.movieRepo = movieRepo;
        this.repertoireRepo = repertoireRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("showForm")
    public String showStudentForm(Movie movie) {
        return "add-movie";
    }

    @GetMapping("list")
    public String getMovies(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("movies", movieRepo.findAll());
        return "movieIndex";
    }

    @PostMapping("add")
    public String movies(@Validated Movie movie, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-movie";
        }

        movieRepo.save(movie);
        return "redirect:/movies/list";
    }

    @GetMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable ("id") long id, Model model) {
        Movie movie = movieRepo.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Nieprawidłowe ID: " + id));

        model.addAttribute("movie", movie);
        return "update-movie";
    }

    @PostMapping("update/{id}")
    public String updateMovie(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Validated Movie movie, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            movie.setId(id);
            return "update-movie";
        }
        movieRepo.save(movie);

        model.addAttribute("movies", movieRepo.findAll());
        return "movieIndex";
    }

    @GetMapping("delete/{id}")
    public String deleteMovie(@PathVariable ("id") long id, Model model) {

        List<Repertoire> repertoires = repertoireRepo.findByMovieId(id);
        repertoires.forEach(r -> repertoireRepo.deleteById(r.getId()));

        Movie movie = movieRepo.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Nieprawidłowe ID : " + id));

        movieRepo.delete(movie);
        model.addAttribute("movies", movieRepo.findAll());
        return "movieIndex";

    }



// HERE'S WHERE I ADD THE TIME:

    @GetMapping("/admin/{movieName}/newRepertoire")
    public String showRepertoireForm(Model model, @PathVariable ("movieName") String movieName) {

        Movie movieRepertoire = movieRepo.findByTitle(movieName);
        model.addAttribute("movieRepertoire", movieRepertoire);
        model.addAttribute("repertoire", new Repertoire());
        return "repertoire";
    }

    @PostMapping("/admin/newRepertoire")
    @Transactional
    public String addRepertoire(@ModelAttribute ("repertoire") Repertoire repertoire,
                                @ModelAttribute("movieRepertoire") Movie movie, BindingResult result) {
//        if(result.hasErrors()) {
//            return "repertoire";
//        }


        repertoire.setMovie(movieRepo.findByTitle(movie.getTitle()));
        repertoireRepo.save(repertoire);
        return "redirect:/movies/list";
    }
}
```

RepertoireRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface RepertoireRepo extends JpaRepository<Repertoire, Long> {
    List<Repertoire> findByMovieId(Long movieId);
}
```

MovieRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepo extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {
    Movie findByTitle(String title);
}
```

repertoire.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>c</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h1 th:text="${movieRepertoire.title}"> MovieName</h1>
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/movies/admin/newRepertoire}" th:object="${repertoire}" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <label for="date" class="col-form-label">Date</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{date}" class="form-control" id="date" value="2021-01-20T13:01">
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('date')}" th:errors="*{date}" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8"></div>
                    </div>
<!--                    <input type = "hidden" th:value="${movieRepertoire}">-->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Movie structure:

```
id | category | description | imageurl| lenght| minage| title
 ------------------------- 
36 | Action | Simple desc. | photo.jpg | 137 | 7 | Iron Man |
```

Repertoire structure:

```
id | date | movie_id
------------------------- 
37 | 2021-01-01 14:00:00 | null |
```

Comment: `GenerationType.IDENTITY` will only work with a database identity column (auto increment on MySQL for instance) in the database side. Can you show your table structure?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed every `GenerationType.IDENTITY` to `GenerationType.AUTO`.      My table structure: (Is this what You meant? - I don't know how to write it properly in commenct section) id | category | description | imageurl| lenght| minage| title
-------------------------
 36 | Action        | Simple desc. | photo.jpg | 137 | 7 | Iron Man`
 
 id | date | movie_id 
-------------------------
 37 | 2021-01-01 14:00:00 | null

Comment: @Cobra9 don't put code in comments, instead update original Question

Comment: Done. I dont know why it still gives null, everything seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Both sides of the relationship must be updated and you should cascade save from the parent. Your code:

```
    repertoire.setMovie(movieRepo.findByTitle(movie.getTitle()));
    repertoireRepo.save(repertoire);
```

Should become:

```
    Movie movie = movieRepo.findByTitle(movie.getTitle());
    movie.getRepertoires().add(repertoire);
    repertoire.setMovie(movie);
    session.saveOrUpdate(movie);
```

In fact really you should add a helper method to Movie that performs both actions to ensure both sides of the relationship are always in sync:

```
public void addRepertoire(Repertoire repertoire) {
  repertoires.add(repertoire);
  repertoire.setMovie(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have 2 question. Is saveOrUpdate the method i have to write on my own, or can use from hibernate annotations? Because it says that can not resolve this method. Second question is: I can't use movie because of already in use and it might not have been initialized

Comment: saveOrUpdate is a method on the Hibernate session. Not sure what you mean by "movie might not have been initialised" as your code has just loaded a movie from the database.